# lmdb.Error: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: python

I just encountered below error in python3 that seems related in lmdb package and my disk or ram space.

My ram is 8GB and HDD is 900GB. it seemed that 1099511627776 byte is about 1TB.

It is ram error or disk error? And I need 1099511627776 byte space in my HDD to solve below error?

```
env = lmdb.open(outputPath, map_size=1099511627776)
lmdb.Error: D:\ocr_kor-master\ocr_kor-master\deep-text-recognition-benchmark\data_lmdb_release\training;: There is not enough space on the disk.
```

Comment: 1099511627776 bytes = 1099GB and see this "There is not enough space on the disk"

Comment: if it is caused because of RAM it will theow [MemoryError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing:

```
env = lmdb.open(outputPath, map_size=1099511627776)
```

to

```
env = lmdb.open(outputPath, map_size=1073741824)
```

worked for me

Comment: Thanks, it is a related problem of HDD(SDD) space.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem because I ran out of open file descriptors.
You can increase the number of allowed file descriptors though it is not typically a good solution to your problem as noted by @osbor in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1577113/402428).

To view and then increase the limit you can use `ulimit -a` and set the limit with `ulimit -u <number>`

```
ulimit -a      # show limits
ulimit -u 2048 # update file descriptor limit
```

See this question for more information: [Is there a fix for the "Too many open files in system" error on OS X 10.7.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1)

Finally, I recommend finding out whether your app using lmdb is properly closing and releasing file descriptors. That would be the complete solution to your issue. Maybe you need to do graceful shutdown with SIGTERM rather than killing a process. This was my issue. I was killing processes without releasing file descriptors and eventually my quantity of available file descriptors was exhausted.